# Get Akamai Token for IPTV HLS

Tags: post, nginx, token, access-token, akamai

Can anyone solve the way I can generate akamai streaming token from the browser when the android app is not available?

I get this string from the app :

```
<--
POST /api/tibo324/getakamaitoken HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 328
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: tibodrm.appspot.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)

<--
auth=84Kwfr741QQv%252BnUMXtW%252FcbZ6aWNQKN0mCAVccmjo%252FXaf6PaB2pz7j3QqAlxHaj%252Fut%252Bu3vSzDt8NO%250AKqNBIgM7ckBedzNMkGOBRtlFfi3gAUuUzYvFN7U9ClHQKKWtfL%252F%252FyB2o1qyvGc2tY8i8lud%252F3tqg%250AhyjUvUD3Bib11V9aQqx8JOBslArMz%252FUaXLR0skPUETIeQatFmGmhFoyuyPhgbg%253D%253D%250A&AppID=v%252B10zWNKL8RJ8SY6LUSZXg%253D%253D%250A

-->
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 26 Dec 2017 22:24:09 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 118
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: Express
ETag: W/"76-zi4HHRQAuAUejh/FF9M5ZFJtPek"
Via: 1.1 google
Alt-Svc: hq=":443"; ma=2592000; quic=51303431; quic=51303339; quic=51303338; quic=51303337; quic=51303335,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="41,39,38,37,35"

-->
?__token__=ip=00.000.00.000~exp=1514332929~acl=*~hmac=e9afdfe9f6b41c0ca14a16bc60a11253aecd432243789144c1ebaa70f23c615e
```

When I try to fetch the following URL:

```
https://tibodrm.appspot.com/api/tibo324/getakamaitoken?auth=84Kwfr741QQv%2BnUMXtW%2FcbZ6aWNQKN0mCAVccmjo%2FXaf6PaB2pz7j3QqAlxHaj%2FuFjEcIocduH6Z%0Awc5ZzKaqnmHhinePCNCcvQfh68bi2UvbZq04lBalY0job9%2FyVeuV1kh4hzWnP8sVuRozO27rFhSY%0AmDB8ck%2FuN0SqKEoxzycGUGhaZy3bjy88%2BhhwEMQknGNJ2j2JdMIHMT0AcLTFoQ%3D%3D%0A&AppID=v%2B10zWNKL8RJ8SY6LUSZXg%3D%3D%0A
```

I get a response in the browser:

> Cannot GET /api/tibo324/getakamaitoken

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your question: you can't GET the URL because it's accessed via POST only. And it looks like the POST requires an authentication string that's generated via the app. Making a POST without any data returns a descriptive error string:

```
$ http POST https://tibodrm.appspot.com/api/tibo324/getakamaitoken
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Alt-Svc: hq=":443"; ma=2592000; quic=51303431; quic=51303339; quic=51303338; quic=51303337; quic=51303335,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="41,39,38,37,35"
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 27 Dec 2017 21:44:19 GMT
ETag: W/"31-zIZow+wVfq5Z3stS2NUNRdvP0go"
Server: nginx
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Via: 1.1 google
X-Powered-By: Express

{
    "description": "no token at all",
    "isValid": false
}
```

The inability to access the token generator through unauthenticated web calls is usually by design as the token is a protective tool Akamai provides customers to prevent access to content outside of the content provider's control.

In short, the content provider you're looking at doesn't want you to access their video outside of their application. If the application isn't able to access the video then you should reach out to the content provider to get that issue fixed rather than trying to circumvent their security scheme.

Comment: Josh, thanks for you're answer! Your comment about the POST data give me the solution!
I used the GET with the browser but since as you said the server uses POST then I just used the data I posted above:

`auth=84Kwfr741QQ....' 

as POST data and it gave me the token! So now i can finally watch my streams outside of the app! :)